# How do you solve for the probability of one outcome from two independent sources of uncertainty?

Tags: probability

**Setup**

You have two boxes. Box A has a 50% chance of having the 'desired prize' and Box B has a 25% chance of having the 'desired prize'. You get to keep box A and box B.

Box A and Box B are independent of each other and so it is possible for both of them to have or not have the box. It is possible to not get the desired prize at all, or to receive duplicates of the 'desired prize'.

**Question**

What are the chances the 'desired prize' is in at least one of your boxes?

Comment: You have provided insufficient information for any sensible answer to be given to your question.  How is it decided whether or not I win the prize?   Do I know which box is which?  Do I get to choose which box to open and keep whatever I find in it?  Can both of the boxes contain the prize, and, if so, is the presence of the prize in each box independent of its presence in the other?  Can I open both boxes and keep whatever I find?

Comment: That is not enough information. Do you have to select one box? Do you already own the two boxes? Might there be two prizes?

Comment: I think OP means: there is one prize. It is in one of the two boxes. And you must choose which one. But then, I might underestimate OPs intention.

Comment: Do you care about someone winning 2 prizes (I mean: perhaps the sponsor does)?

Answer (score 1):

The chance of the prize being in at least one of the two boxes means that we have 3 possible scenarios.

- **Scenario 1: the desired prize is in both boxes**

This is simply $0.5$x $0.25$ = $0.125$ as we multiply the probability of the prize being in box A with the probability of it being in box B.

- **Scenario 2: the desired prize is only in box A**

This is now $0.5$ x $(1-0.25)$ = $0.5$x $0.75$ = $0.375$ as we multiply the probability of the prize being in box A with the probability of it **not** being in box B.

- **Scenario 3: the desired prize is only in box B**

This is, similarly to above, $(1-0.5)$ x $0.25$ = $0.5$x $0.25$ = $0.125$ as we multiply the probability that the prize is **not** in box A with the probability of it being in box B.

**Final Answer**

The final step is now just to add up the 3 probabilities as these cover all the situations that you are looking for.

And so our final answer will be $0.125 + 0.375 + 0.125$ $=$ $0.625$

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the comment of Bey, following my answer, the responses here seem to be a case of **shooting gallery blues**, where the target has moved.

---

Very interesting opposing answers and comments, all of which I disagree with.  The exception is the interpretation in, and answer of FD_bfa, which I agree with.

This is my alternative approach, given that interpretation:

To me, it seems that the OP's (i.e. original poster's) intention is clear:

- Event $E_1$ is the event that there is a prize in Box A. 
  $p(E_1) = (1/2).$
- Event $E_2$ is the event that there is a prize in Box B. 
  $p(E_2) = (1/4).$
- Events $E_1$ and $E_2$ are **independent** events.
- The OP is asking (in effect) what is the probability that it is not the case that both events $E_1$ and $E_2$ fail.

Since the $2$ events are independent, and since the probability of failure in the $2$ events $E_1$ and $E_2$ are $(1/2)$ and $(3/4)$ respectively, the probability that both events fail is $(1/2) \times (3/4) = 3/8$.

Therefore, the probability that it is not the case that both events $E_1$ and $E_2$ fail must be

$$1 - (3/8).$$

Comment: This wasn’t what the statement was earlier — it’s been heavily edited.

Comment: @Bey Outstanding point, which never occurred to me.  See the just added paragraph at the start of my answer.

Comment: Haven't heard of "shooting gallery blues" before, but I guess it alludes to the fact that we both filled in the gaps with different assumptions and someone (me) ended up off the mark.

Comment: @Bey In a shooting gallery, the target is constantly moving.

Comment: I agree, but, when 'very interesting opposing answers and comments, all of which you disagree with' were written, question itself looked different :-) Have a nice day!

Comment: @FirstNameLastName Agreed, that the implied criticism is unjust, given that the posting was different.  And agreed, that I totally overlooked that the posting might have changed.  So, **why** didn't I simply revise the initial part of my answer, instead of prefacing it?  **Answer**: because I wanted new mathSE posters to observe the havoc caused when someone posts a question without first thoroughly proofreading it, for mistakes or ambiguities.